# how to display sensetive string in python

Tags: python

So, I have a file with content like below where it is mixed with sensetive and non-sensetive data

```
tableName_password = "password" 
name="text"
```

so, when I display the content of the file it shows the password as `"password"`.
Hence my question is how can I display the `"password" as ****` only for display, without actually changing the real value inside the file and without impacting the display of non-sensetive data.

```
with open(file_location) as file:
        print(file.read())
```

it will only display not changing the value `"password"` in other word, it will mask the actual value for password while untouching the name.

```
tableName_password = "****"
name="text"
```

Comment: where will you display this password? in the terminal, returned as a response from some web endpoint?

Comment: in the terminal. just for debugging.

Comment: so you want to "mask" the password in the terminal?

Comment: Word of caution: you shouldn't keep passwords in plain text. If you can, you should use environment variables or user input with getpass.

Comment: i know, that's why I would like to display as masking when I try to debug other contents of the file which are non-sensetive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
import re

with open(file_path) as file:
        masked = re.sub(r'.', '*', file.read())
        print(masked)
```

Returns: `*****`

Comment: this answer is technically correct, because the password will be redacted. However, this will match every character and substitute it with *, which is a bit heavy handed. You would need to construct a proper pattern to avoid "greedy" substitution

Answer (score 0):

> there is a method in python Prompt the user for a password without echoing [getpass()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass)

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
print(password)
```

Comment: while i share your anxiety about passwords stored in plain text, this doesn't address the question. What if the questioner can't take a user prompt? This could be part of a large set of data that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way of replacing all the password characters with asterisks would be to use the builtin [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```py
password = "something123"
masked_pass = ''.join(map(lambda _: '*', password))
print(masked_pass)
```

Output

```py
************
```

`map` changes every character inside `password` to a `*`, `''.join()` joins them all into a string.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest version is:

```
original_pass = 'your_pass'
masked_pass = '*'*len(original_pass)
print(masked_pass)
```

Comment: I think the questioner's big problem is not answered by this: how do you identify the password to then mask it? This answer assumes that the questioner has already done this, which I don't think is true.

Comment: @PirateNinjas he has written `I have a file with content like below` - so I think he knows what is the name of the key, which stores the password.

Comment: They do, yes, but knowing the structure is one thing. Knowing how to procedurally extract the information using that structure is another

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer, I am going to suggest that you use an alternative approach for whatever it is you're doing. It's generally not a good idea to store passwords as plain text in an easily accessible file!

As for your problem, I would probably use a regular expression, like so:

```
import re


with open(file_location) as file:
    contents = file.read()
    print(
        re.sub("(?P<password>(password\s*=\s*)).*$", r"\2****", contents)
    )
```

This works by matching any string that has "{anything else}password = {whatever value}" at the end of a line. It will then substitute this with some * symbols to hide the data.